# Proper workflow for newbie to SVN-IDE environment

Tags: eclipse, svn, netbeans, ide, workflow

I'm an interaction designer/front-end developer who has until now worked on relatively basic and loosely structured web environments. Typically I used Dreamweaver, edit a local copy of the site, had a remote development server and production server. Even when working in a small team we weren't sophisticated - no version control besides some basic DW functionality.

I'm now on a more sophisticated team working on web applications. We use subversion (and, wow, it's damn handy) and everyone has their own development instance. I've adapted my old way of doing things to this new environment, so I'm still using Dreamweaver. Because others want to be able to view/diff my code even before I check things in, I'm currently have a subversion checkout on both my local machine (using Tortoise, easy for me as a newbie, and I edit in DW) and on my instance of the dev server. So I have to do SVN updates twice to stay in sync.

I'm doing enough php and javascript now that I realized I really should switch to Netbeans, Eclipse or some other more sophisticated IDE. At the same time, I'd like to improve my workflow.

Can an IDE meet my needs for subversion management? Should I try to move completely away from editing on my machine and instead work directly on my dev instance?

I've played around with Netbeans and am leaning towards using that, but would love thoughts on that as well. The people I work with now as "real" programmers so what I have been doing baffles them enough that they can't relate (and give me good advice).

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I recommend SmartSVN. It's a standalone app and far more sophisticated than anything I've ever seen in Eclipse, Komodo, etc. It's also free for personal use. As for your IDE, it's a matter of preference, if not necessity. I would say try Aptana first, it's based on Eclipse and geared toward your line of work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what we've setup for our development teams:

- Each developer has their local machine which is Windows and has the SVN repos checked out.
- Each developer has a LAMP VM that matches our production web servers.
- We use samba on the LAMP VM's to share the `/var/www` directory and map the shared network location on our local machines.
- Developers edit the source files locally using Netbeans.
- Our Netbeans project has an option to copy any changed files to a separate location.

This allows everything to stay local, everything remote stays up to date, and the remote server doesn't have all the extra SVN files.

Drawbacks:

- Have to SVN Update from Netbeans or the changes might not be copied to the remote server.

  - You can still recover from a bad remote server state by doing an SVN Export
  - You do not need to do a SVN Commit from Netbeans though. I still prefer TortoiseSVN for this.
- When you add files externallay (like from Windows Explorer) such as images, you have to Scan for External changes to have them copied to the remote server.

  - I don't know if Netbeans 7.0 has resolved this as it now checks the OS file events.

Comment: The last point you mention "option to copy any changed files to a separate location" - what's that for? I assume that's separate from any SVN commits?

Comment: Yes, the copy option (under Project Properties, Sources, Copy files from Sources Folder to another location) is just to make sure the edited files are on the dev's remote webserver. Once all changes have been made, an SVN commit is issued from the local machine. This way everything is tested on a machine that matches production and the dev's local machine doesn't need a webserver.